# php - Protect resources from outside use

Tags: php, ajax, http

In my application I'm using many times one resource with JSON data, eg. `books`. Is it possible to protect this data from use outside of server? Eg.
On server address (127.0.0.1) I'm getting normally data but from another IP (2.2.2.2) I'm getting error, not data.

On website I'm using simple ajax:

```
bookGetCategories.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/remote/categories',
        data: { 'book': $(this).data('id') },
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // sth with data
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
        alert("Eee... We got a problem.");
    });
});
```

Comment: how are you loading your JSON data?

Comment: @Kaddath Simple ajax, I updated question.

Comment: what you can do is request a path to a folder to trigger execution of an `index.php` inside it (it seems that you do it already), or a folder with a `.htaccess` in it (to transform an URL element in a param, for exemple `cat/book1` rewritten in `cat/index.php?book=book1` for the situation where there can be multiple resource files). The key point is to call a php file instead of the resource itself. In the php file you can check all security conditions like IP, and display the requested file as response (or directly raw data if the case fits)